# How would one permanently set names for network interface (wifi/ethernet) in arch

Tags: arch-linux, wicd

Seems every reboot the names reverse different nics ( wifi/ethernet )…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `udev`. In Gentoo and many other distributions it is done automatically but you may want to base on that if you want quick'n'dirty solution:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib64/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10f5 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC_ADDRESS>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x4236 (iwlagn)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC_ADDRESS>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

Did you changed any `udev` configuration?